# What is the meaning of a gray/gradient border on a question

Tags: support, questions, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I left my SO tab open open at a question in Firefox and when I came back a couple of hours later I saw the question with a gray gradient border:

[image]

The gray border remained when I loaded the "1 new answer" but disappeared when I hit reload in the browser.  I've seen this before but have never been able to duplicate the conditions under which it occurs.

Comment: It's known as the _"Jon Skeet's Midas touch"_. Honestly I have no clue.

Comment: ^ Replacing @Will here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have keyboard commands turned on, and that highlighting indicates the currently selected post for further commands with your keyboard. Pressing the <kbd>U</kbd> key selects the question, so you must have hit it at some point when you weren't inside an input field.

Comment: Pressing `J` may also select the question

Comment: That is it.  Curiously, NOW the sidebar shows a couple of questions of which this one is a dupe, but at the time I wrote the question the sidebar most definitely did not show the dupes.  I specifically kept checking as I typed to see if the system would show me a dup. Is this dup-finding an asynchronous process?  I guess that's a new question., which I'll post.