# Dup-finding for questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, search

See [What is the meaning of a gray/gradient border on a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335080/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-gray-gradient-border-on-a-question)

The sidebar now shows two questions that answer my question (so mine could be closed as a dup).  However, being an experienced SO user I ALWAYS check the sidebar as I'm typing to see if the system finds potential duplicates.

I even searched for "gray gradient" before I started posting my question but there were no potential hits.

Is the potential dup search asynchronous, such that the sidebar can populate over time (on refresh, I guess)?  Is there any way to make the search facility more capable? It should have found "gray gradient" since those words appear in the other question's title.

Comment: I mostly use google to find dups, the SE search engine is often poor.

Comment: Maybe you didn't find it because you spelled it "gray" and the linked question spelled it "grey"... Interesting how search results differ drastically with the two forms.

Comment: The SE internal search has always been "slightly interesting" - there's been numerous posts about it. Ironically in chat - it works better. I tend to find posts more easily via google unless I have to use `deleted:1` or `deleted:all` operators that can only be done internally.